# How to delete leftover commands in IPython console?

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

I recently opened Spyder after a really long time, and my IPython console immediately showed some leftover commands? Do they affect my next code, and if they do, how can I get rid of them? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKxKb.png)

**EDIT** Solved: all i had to do is turn off symbolic mathematics in preferences/ipython console/advanced settings. When I turn it back on, it shows again. I would like to know is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Please insert text here and don't use images for this.

Comment: okay, sorry, it's my first time posting here